# How to clear global variables when exiting app in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a global variable `usersSerivce.js` like this:

```js
let user = null;
let loadedScreens = {};

/**
 * Return user information and the number of times this screen gets user information
 * @param {string} The screen name
 * @returns Promise<{user:any,loadCount:number}>
 */
export function getUser(screenName) {
  return Promis.resolve(user).then(_usr => {
    if (!_usr) {
      return ajax.get("get user api"); // a Promise
    } else {
      return _usr;
    }
  }).then(_usr => {
    //Here, I have user information.
    user = _usr;
    //Record the screen load user count.
    loadedScreens[screenName] = (loadedScreens[screenName] || 0) + 1;
    return {
      loadCount: loadedScreens[screenName],
      user
    };
  });
}
```

and in `HomeScreen.js`

```js
import { getUser } from "./usersService";
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';

export default class HomeScreen extend Component {
  screenFocus(e) {
    getUser(this.props.navigation.state.routeName).then(({user,loadCount})=>{
      this.setState({user});
      if (loadCount === 1) { //The problem appears in this line
        //Here, in order to prevent the user from loading the page data each time the Home page is entered,
        //the loading is performed only when the user information is read for the first time.
        ajax.get("get current user tasks list API").then(tasks=>{
          this.setState({tasks});
        })
      }
    })
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <NavigationEvents onDidFocus={(e)=>this.screenFocus(e)}/>
        {/*other components*/}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

This does not seem to have any problems.

But in Android, I click on the `hardware [return]` button to exit the app. When I open the app again, the `loadCount` returned by `getUser` is **not** `1`, and the `state.tasks` and `state.user` in `HomeScreen` are both `undefined`(`HomeScreen` has been remount), when I read After the user information, the task information cannot be loaded again.

Why is the global variable `loadedScreens` not recycled when the app exits, causing this variable to still exist when I open the app again? And how do I reset loadScreens when the app exits?

> PS: If I open the app list of Android and quit the app completely after I quit the app, there is no such problem.

Comment: Hi Lession,
you can use `componentWillUnmount` for perform clean up actions.
you have to reset/clear your variables using this hook

Comment: Hi, @KishanGujarati, Thanks for your help!
I was dizzy before, because I don't want to clean up the data for each Screen. Now I have initialized these global variables in the constructor of the App component, which has been resolved, thanks

Comment: great
you're welcome